# Finding the classpath of a web app

Tags: java, web-applications, classpath

When I'm working on my web app in Eclipse, I can search all the classes and JAR files with

```
String cp = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

but when I deploy on Tomcat or Jetty, I get nothing.

I want to find all `*.properties` files which are located in the webapp (either in the JAR or, if exploded, in folders).

```
String cp = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
String pathSep = File.pathSeparator;
String[] jarOrDirectories = cp.split(pathSep);
for (String fileName : jarOrDirectories) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (file.isFile()) {
                logger.debug("From jar "+file.getName());
                loadFromJar(file.getPath());
        } else {
                logger.debug("From folder "+file.getName());
                listFolder(file);
        }
}
```

This way, running the web application in Eclipse gives me all JAR files and all class folders, but not when I deploy the application in Tomcat.

It would be enough if I could just get the path to `WEB_INF`. From there, it's easy.

Comment: The java.class.path property probably isn't what you want.  Webapps have custom classloader hierarchies that affect visibility.  See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html for more information.  can you provide a code sample that demonstrates what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If someone needs the answer, I found a very obvious answer.

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF")
```

Then when you receive the real path you can easily search through the folders and JARs.

Comment: Awesome ! This just saved my bacon for JBoss 7.1.3. :-)